# Removing invalid characters from XML in Python3 with etree

Tags: xml, python-3.x, encoding, elementtree

I have a XML file encoded in UTF-8 with some bad content that brokes my script when I try to parse it with:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree  
etree.parse(file).getroot()
```

I've seen some old answers where they use "recover=True" in the parser but after reading etree's docs it seems it's not allowed anymore.
Also I can't manually replace the characters because I'm afraid this could happen again in the future with other characters, so I'm looking for a solution that completely removes any single non-allowed character.
Is there any built-in function or way of doing this?

Comment: The `recover` option is available in lxml, but not in ElementTree. See https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html.

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced the library and it's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I just replaced the library for lxml and used the "recover" option for the parser. It's working fine now.

Comment: hello can you please furnish more detail to your code? 
I know it's an old topic but that would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

in a similar use case i have this issue

```
exception = SAXParseException('reference to invalid character number')
```

that because my xml has this characters

```
&#x1F;&#x1F;&#x1F;
```

this is my code to solve the problem

```
from lxml import etree
my_parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
xml = etree.fromstring(dirty_xml_string, parser=my_parser)
cleaned_xml_string = etree.tostring(xml)
```

it works in my use-case